# How can I host a non-static React SPA app on S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, hosting

Friends,

Can I host a standard React-redux SPA application (non-static website) on AWS S3 instead of hosting on a web server like IIS? I want to take advantage of higher availability and cost by deploying it on S3.

May I please know is this the right thing to do? What threats I'm exposed to by deploying such kind of website on S3 instead of IIS? Like how do I add security headers in response? (probably by a lambda I guess) but what else I'm missing?

This is very important for me to know so looking out for some help/suggestion on this. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to host non static websites on S3. It is called "Static website hosting" explicitly.